# Inner join does not work with recursion selection

Tags: mysql, recursion

I have some tables:

```
product(id)

product_locale(product_id, locale_id)

category_product(category_id, product_id)
```

I want to select all products of a category and it's subcategories.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.added,
       a.seller,
       a.position,
       c.title,
       c.alias
FROM product a
INNER JOIN product_locale c ON a.id = c.product_id
INNER JOIN category_product d ON d.product_id = a.id
WHERE c.locale_id = 1
  AND (d.category_id = 17
       OR d.category_id in
         (SELECT id
          FROM
            (SELECT *
             FROM category
             ORDER BY parent,
                      id) category_sorted,

            (SELECT @pv := 17) initialisation
          WHERE find_in_set(parent, @pv)
            AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))))
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

Basically, I have a sub query to get all the sub categories of the current category:

```
SELECT id
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM category
   ORDER BY parent,
            id) category_sorted,

  (SELECT @pv := 17) initialisation
WHERE find_in_set(parent, @pv)
  AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Here is the categories structure:

17 > 19 > 33 > 35

If I run the sub query separately, I got the right results (19, 33 and 35), so I expect the query should be:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.added,
       a.seller,
       a.position,
       c.title,
       c.alias
FROM product a
INNER JOIN product_locale c ON a.id = c.product_id
INNER JOIN category_product d ON d.product_id = a.id
WHERE c.locale_id = 1
  AND (d.category_id = 17
       OR d.category_id in (19,
                            33,
                            35))
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

If I run this query, I got right results. However, if I run the query with sub query, no records returned.

If I use left join instead the inner join like bellow query, it works:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.added,
       a.seller,
       a.position,
       c.title,
       c.alias
FROM product a
LEFT JOIN product_locale c ON a.id = c.product_id
AND c.locale_id = 1
INNER JOIN category_product d ON d.product_id = a.id
WHERE (d.category_id = 17
       OR d.category_id in
         (SELECT id
          FROM
            (SELECT *
             FROM category
             ORDER BY parent,
                      id) category_sorted,

            (SELECT @pv := 17) initialisation
          WHERE find_in_set(parent, @pv)
            AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))))
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

But if I move the condition c.locale_id = 1 to where condition, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.added,
       a.seller,
       a.position,
       c.title,
       c.alias
FROM product a
LEFT JOIN product_locale c ON a.id = c.product_id
INNER JOIN category_product d ON d.product_id = a.id
WHERE c.locale_id = 1
  AND (d.category_id = 17
       OR d.category_id in
         (SELECT id
          FROM
            (SELECT *
             FROM category
             ORDER BY parent,
                      id) category_sorted,

            (SELECT @pv := 17) initialisation
          WHERE find_in_set(parent, @pv)
            AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))))
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

I expected that the sub query doesn't affect to the query, however, seem it does.

Comment: If you need a recursing problem solved, ook at using Recursive CTEs.

Comment: Is safe if I create a variable to store the initial category ID?

@pv := 17; with recursive cte

Comment: From [MySQL-8.0 deprecations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations) "Support for setting user variables in statements other than SET was deprecated in MySQL 8.0.13. This functionality is subject to removal in MySQL 9.0.". `17` isn't a variable in a recursive part of the CTE, its the [initial rowset query of the recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive).

Comment: You might find this old [MySQL Blog post](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-three-hierarchies/) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

please use below code:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.added,
       a.seller,
       a.position,
       c.title,
       c.alias
FROM product a
INNER JOIN product_locale c ON a.id = c.product_id AND c.locale_id = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM category
        ORDER BY parent, id
    ) category_sorted
    JOIN (
        SELECT @pv := 17
    ) initialisation
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parent, @pv) AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))
) subcategories ON d.category_id = subcategories.id
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

i've moved the c.locale_id = 1 condition back into the INNER JOIN with product_locale, ensuring that you only retrieve products where the locale matches.